# Excel VBA - Macro to Filter Column if Contains Any Values from Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I've scoured the site for years, but first post, so hopefully I'm clear in the Q description.

I've got a worksheet, A-H, 1-100. In Columns C,D,E, there are singular, non-unique values. In Column G, there's a string of values which may contain one or more of the values from C,D,E.

I'm trying to put together a macro that:
-Prompts the user to select cells/range in columns C,D,E
-Filters G for any rows that contain those values.

Currently method attempt:

- On button click, prompt user to select cells/range
- Format Range into "="*XX*" or "*XX*"...
- Drop string into a cell
- Back in the Worksheet, the user would use the cell as a criteria for Advanced Filetering.

I've been looking all over different forums and can't find a solution for this. I'm pretty green in scripting, but am so far able to prompt the user to select cell, take the values and drop them to a cell in the format [*XX*" or "*XX*" or "*XX*" ...] (where X's are the values from the selected C,D,E range)[out]. When I try to add the "="" to the front [oout], I get an error on run.

I don't know if this is the best method, or if I should approach from a different direction. Any input would help. Thanks

```
Sub Button84_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim out As String
Dim oout As String
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select All Characters in Oper", "Get Cells", Type:=8)
out = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("*" & Chr(34) & " or " & Chr(34) & "*", True, rng)
oout = WorksheetFunction.Concat(Chr(61) & Chr(34) & "*", out, "*" & Chr(34))
Debug.Print oout
Range("V1").Value = oout
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you have an unlimited number of inputs (selected cells), I would probably loop through each selected cell.  For each selected cell, I would then loop through column G and if the cell contains the value, then I would increment column I (a new column after H) by 1.  Then, after the loop, I would filter for Col I > 0.  You'd have to set all values in Col I to zero before beginning the loop.  In VBA, looping through a column is almost instantaneous unless you have a huge database.  This method might be less complicated to code than applying many filters.

Comment: Thank You - I was trying to avoid a helper column since most related posts I could find had much clunkier sounding solutions. That sounds like a much more straightforward and clean method. Going to give it a shot. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are particular, you can hide the helper column or set the width so it is invisible.  Or, there is probably a way to add the column on the fly, use it, filter on it, then delete it, though without trying it I couldn't say for sure if that was worth the time.  The fact that your question has gone unanswered for a whole day suggests there isn't a clean-code way to do it.

Comment: I feel like I'm so close!

Comment: Ugh - I can't figure out how to put my code in - Trying to make a new post under this section.